# Jquery Validation for dynamically added rows that has multiple element with same name

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

Adding table row dynamically based on some `count`

```
        var del_count=$("#trainee_count").val();
        var row_counter=0;
        for(var i=0;i<del_count;i++){
        row_counter++;
        $(".add_trainee").append(   
            '<tr>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="name"  class="required"  /></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="jobTitle"  /></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="email"  id="email" class="required email"  /></td>'+
                '<td><input type="text" name="phone" class="required phone"   /></td>'+
                '<td  class="my_laptop" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" class="laptop_checkbox"   name="isLaptopRequired.'+row_counter+'"  checked /></td>'+
            '</tr>' 

            );
        }
```

Basically I am trying do the validation for multiple element with same name.

validation:

```
    $(".traineeDetailsForm").validate({ 
                errorContainer: "#error_div",
                errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}
            });
```

i may have 'n' number of rows , that will have 'n' number of elements with same name
Here validation applies for only the first row(tr)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot validate multiple inputs sharing the same `name`.  The jQuery Validate plugin requires that every input contain a *unique* `name` because the `name` is how the plugin keeps track of the inputs.

The solution is simply to use a counter as part of the `name` ensuring that it's unique, just like you did with your checkbox...

```
$(".add_trainee").append(   
        '<tr>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="name' + count + '"  class="required"  /></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="jobTitle' + count + '"  /></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="email' + count + '"  id="email" class="required email"  /></td>'+
            '<td><input type="text" name="phone' + count + '" class="required phone"   /></td>'+
            '<td  class="my_laptop" align="center" valign="middle"><input type="checkbox" class="laptop_checkbox"   name="isLaptopRequired.'+row_counter+'"  checked /></td>'+
        '</tr>' );
```

Also see this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/18905194/594235

Answer (score -1):

Use .each() to validate multiple element with the same name.

```
$(".traineeDetailsForm").each(function () {
     $(this).validate({ 
          errorContainer: "#error_div",
          errorPlacement: function(error, element) {}
     });
});
```